# Empty/Invalid Field-Path when creating a reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Problem**

Hi, I want to read data from the firestore in my android-app. However whenever I create a reference the following error occurs:

```
Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
//...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid field path (``). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..'
```

[Entire Log](https://pastebin.com/0WFUV9Vx)

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hub);

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();    // this does not result in the error
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("a");  // this does result in the error
}
```

[Firestore-Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMnX5.png)

---

**Expected Behavior**

Receiving the collectionReference from the specified fieldPath.

**Actual Behavior**

FieldPath is empty resulting in internal firestore-error.

---

**Questions**

1. Why is the path invalid/empty?
2. How can I fix the path?

Comment: I am very certain that the one line of code is not causing the error you're seeing.  Could you debug a bit more and locate the actual lines of relevant code so we can see what you're doing here?

Comment: I can understand the doubt but I already narrowed it down to this line. As the log says the error occurs internally in firestore and it only occurs when requesting data from it. In order to give you a better image of whats going on I edited the question to show the entire method.

Comment: You said that you're reading data, but you aren't showing any code where you read anything.  All you're showing is the creation of a collection reference.

Comment: My goal is to read data from firestore. Therefore I'm trying to get the collection reference. When creating the reference the described internal error occurs. I adjusted the problem description in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Before the error occurred I queried over entries that were structured like email-addresses. Could this query result in invalid paths in firestore?